# Can I use $||J||_2$ as a "gradient descent" for the system $J = b - Ax$?

Tags: systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, normed-spaces, gradient-descent

One quick question.
Let's assume that I want to solve $Ax = b$ but I want to do that in a special way.
My idea is that I first find the difference between $b$ and $Ax$, we call it $J$.

$$J = b-Ax$$

And I want to change $x$ so $J$ will be so small as possible. To measure how good $b - Ax$ become, then I can use $L^2$ norm on $J$ e.g $||J||_2$. If $||J||_2$ is large, then it means $x$ is not the right solution. If $||J||_2$$ is small, then perhaps $x$ is the right solution after all.

So my idea of some kind of "gradient descent" for the next $x$ would be.

$$J_k = b - Ax_k$$
$$x_{k+1} = x_k ||J_k||_2$$

Do you think that will work? In this case, $||J||_2$ works as a non-negative varying scaling parameter depending on if previous $x$ is good or bad.

What do you think about that?

Comment: What's the idea behind that $x$-update equation? All of the $x_k$ vectors will point in the same direction, so you're only exploring a line through the origin.

Comment: @littleO Yes, you're right. Do you think there is another way to solve this? if the dimenison of $J$ is not the same as $x$?

Comment: To do a *gradient descent*, you would have to compute the *gradient* of the function $f(x) = \| b -Ax\|_2$. (actually using $f^2$ is better because it is differentiable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is symmetric positive definite, then solving $Ax = b$ is equivalent to minimizing the function $f(x) = \frac12 x^T A x - b^T x$. The reason this is true is that the gradient of $f$ is
$$
\nabla f(x) = Ax - b
$$
and by minimizing $f$ we find a point where $\nabla f(x) = 0$, or equivalently $Ax = b$.

Minimizing $f$ using gradient descent with step size $t > 0$ yields the iteration
$$
x_{k+1} = x_k - t(A x_k - b)
$$
which is somewhat like the idea that you suggested.

---

If $A$ is not symmetric positive definite, we could take $f(x) = \frac12 \| Ax - b \|_2^2$ instead. Then the gradient of $f$ is $\nabla f(x) = A^T (Ax - b)$. The gradient descent iteration with step size $t > 0$ would be
$$
x^+ = x - tA^T(Ax - b).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like it! But what if $A$ is not square? E.g $b$ has not the same dimension as $x$?

Comment: I added an explanation of what we might do in that case. Keep in mind by the way that superior numerical methods are available.

Comment: Good! What if I use $||J||_2 = t$, then the step time would be adaptive?

Comment: By the way! I don't understand why I should use $A^T$ in $x^+ = x - tA^T(Ax-b)$? Sure I undetstand why the transpose, but not $A$ again?

Comment: The $A^T$ appears because that's just what the gradient of $f$ is in that case. It's a question of vector calculus to compute the gradient of $f$. Maybe Google for "gradient of least squares objective function" to find the gradient computation.

Comment: $t = \| J \|_2$ could be one choice for adaptive step size selection, but I suspect it will be overly conservative. The gradient vector approaches $0$ as we approach a minimizer, so the gradient descent steps become smaller even with a fixed parameter $t$. I believe you could choose $t$ by doing an exact line search, and that might be a good way to go.